# Searching i TStringList using POS - need more advanced method

Tags: delphi, search, tstringlist

I use the following function to search a TStringList I am reading from a file.
I know that when I search a value, then the return value I need is always on the line after the one with the item I search.
It has always worked using POS to search, but now the file has been expanded and I have to look for 2 items 'Adresse' and 'Adresse 2' 
That gives me an issue since pos finds 'Adresse' in both cases and my data is then wrong.

Is there another method of searching a string for a substring that I don't know of or do I have to make my own.

```
function FindValue(const aFilename, aSearch: string): string;
var
  InfoList: TStringList;
  Counter: integer;
begin
  InfoList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    InfoList.LoadFromFile(aFilename);
    if InfoList.Count > 0 then
      for Counter := 0 to InfoList.Count - 1 do
        begin
          if Pos(aSearch, Infolist.Strings[Counter]) > 0 then
            Result := Infolist.Strings[Counter + 1]
        end
    else
      Result := '';
  finally
    InfoList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For info: the input to the TStringList comes from a textfile extracted from a HTML file.
A sample of a file could be:

```
OZ8HP
Hugo Pedersen
Radioamatør
Nykøbing M
Sendeposition:
Adresse:
Prinsensvej 18
Postnummer:
7900
Bynavn:
Nykøbing M
Antenne højde (m):
Kote (m):?Kote (m):Brugerens/tilladelsesindehaverens øvrige adresseoplysninger så som Stednavn og/eller Postboks. Hjælpetegnet * kan anvendes, som beskrevet i hjælp.
Koordinater:
Geografisk anvendelse:
Frekvensmaske:
Tekniske specifikationer:
Sendeeffekt basisstation:
Sendeeffekt mobile anlæg:
Båndbredde (MHz):
Antal anlæg:
MMSI:
Kaldesignaltype:
Personlig
Frekvenskategori:
Udstedelses-metode:
Intention om overdragelse:
Nej
Udløbsdato:
Brugerdata:
Brugernummer:
956078
Adresse:
Prinsensvej 18
Adresse 2:
Sejerslev
Postnr.:
7900
Bynavn:
Nykøbing M
Kaldesignal-kategori:
Bestået A
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show us what the input data format looks like.  Tell us it's not HTML or JSON or some such...

Comment: I have put sample of text file in question, but it looks like ....

Comment: Just search for **"Adresse:"** instead of **"Adresse"** ??

Comment: Also when you find the string, why do you keep looking?  Exit the loop when you find the string - Add "Break;" after you set Result

Comment: `the input to the TStringList comes from a textfile extracted from a HTML file.` ... one wonders what the un-extracted HTML looked like.  Did you make your job harder by stripping out tags that you might have used with an HTML parser to objectively fetch the information you're after?

Comment: The unextracted HTML looks strange to me and I have not been able to get the information I need pulled out - maybe one day when I get a lot of time I will give it a go.

Comment: An HTML parser will understand it

Comment: Can you recommend one to try - but I still think I will have some issues. Adresse appears 2 times in the file and sometimes there is data at the first one and sometimes they are at the second. So it is not 'standard' (the HTML comes from a website run by the Danish state, so nothing is standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me as though the real mistake is being too lax in your search. Why accept partial matches? It would seem more robust to look for complete matches

```
if SameText(aSearch, Infolist[Counter]) then
```

or perhaps to account for leading and trailing whitespace:

```
if SameText(aSearch, Trim(Infolist[Counter])) then
```

You'd need to pass `'Adresse:'` or `'Adresse 2:'` as the search string, or add the colon in the search function.

Use `AnsiSameText` if you want locale sensitive comparison. Use `=` if you want case sensitive comparison, etc.

You might pass multiple search strings and be able to loop only once over the file. As it stands you read it twice which seems wasteful. Indeed surely better to operate on a string list and not be coupled to file storage.

You return the last match in the data rather than the first, for instance. What if there are multiple matches? Does your code behave as intended?

You should also be aware that if no match is found your function does not assign to the `Result` variable which means it is undefined.

Comment: I have adapted your input and now I think it is almost as good as it can be.  My worst issue now is that the things I search for may appear 2 times in the file ( already in HTML from http://frekvensregister.erst.dk/Search/Result.aspx?CS=oz8hp ) and that is my next task to get that sorted.